# 502 Bad Gateway nginx php-fpm

Tags: server, php, nginx, php-fpm

I tried to install nginx and PHP7 with FPM using this tutorial:  https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-upgrade-to-php-7-on-ubuntu-14-04

When I try to access any `.php` file I get `502 Bad Gateway`.
When I try to restart `php7.0-fpm`, I get this:

```
sudo service php7.0-fpm restart
stop: Unknown instance: 
php7.0-fpm start/running, process 5379
```

My nginx config:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

My server is Ubuntu Server 14.04

Comment: Check the `/etc/php7.0/fpm/pool.d/www.conf` configuration file and verify that the run path you think PHP is listening on is actually where it listens.   Once PHP is started and running, do you clear your cache on your browser and try and access the PHP again?  Do you see any errors in `/var/log/nginx/error.log`?

Comment: there is no folder `/etc/php7.0`

Comment: `2016/06/18 19:00:02 [crit] 5601#0: *6 connect() to unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 109.236.47.141, server: kida.al, request: "GET /i.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock:", host: "kida.al"`

Comment: My apologies I mistyped the directory path.  Check `/etc/php/7.0/fpm/pool.d/www.conf`.  What does the entry for the `listen =` item say?

Comment: `listen = /run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is likely that an older libpcre3 is installed and satisfies the dependency in the php7.0 package, but only the newer library package provides pcre_jit_stack_free.

If this is the case, do an `apt-get install libpcre3`, and you’re good to go.

Ref.: https://github.com/oerdnj/deb.sury.org/issues/372

Answer (score 4):

Try to check your nginx's www.conf file and make sure the socket path is correct and socket file is present at that location while these services are running.

ie,
`/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock` or

```
/dev/shm/php-fpm-www.sock
```

try to start php-fpm from init.d

```
/etc/init.d/php-7.0.0-fpm start
```

and check your php.ini file also

add the following to the end of the file

```
[apc]
apc.write_lock = 1
apc.slam_defense = 0
```

Comment: `/var/run/php` and `/dev/shm/` are empty.

`/etc/init.d/php-7.0.0-fpm: No such file or directory`

Comment: You can make sure php is running by applying the command for checking the version `php -v`. if php and nginx are alive, then try to find out the php-fpm sock file location.

Comment: I get this error when i run php -v: `php: symbol lookup error: php: undefined symbol: pcre_jit_stack_free`

Answer (score 1):

I'd literally been fighting this for days, when I found the solution. It was a typo in `/etc/nginx/sites-available/www` (copied originally from ...sites-available/default and modified).

I'd overlooked this in both the file itself and the `/var/log/nginx/error.log` --even though the error log was clear

```
connect to unix: /var/run/php/php7.0-fpm-sock failed (2: No such file or directory)
```

The connection line should have read `unix: /var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock`.

Duh.

Comment: what did it say before you corrected it?

Comment: he replaced a dash with a dot

Answer (score 0):

I installed from a guide which used php7.0-fpm-sock ,which I copied pasted into nginx.conf. Making the change to php7.2-fpm-sock solved the issue for me. Would have commented, but i can't do that yet.