# 502 bad gateway nginx php7.0-pfm ubuntu 16.04

Tags: php, nginx

I read this article from a couple months back
[502 Bad Gateway nginx php7 fpm](https://askubuntu.com/questions/788739/502-bad-gateway-nginx-php7-fpm)

I tried a bunch of stuff but I am still getting a 502 bad gateway error.

When I look at the error log I get the following:

```
2017/02/08 08:46:34 [error] 1482#1482: *166935 connect() to unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock failed (11: Resource temporarily unavailable) while connecting to upstream, client: 191.96.249.70, server: example.com, request: "POST /xmlrpc.php HTTP/1.0", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock:", host: "xx.xx.xx.xx"
```

I have a fresh install of Ubuntu 16.04 with the current updates.  My RAM memory is as follows:

```
server:~$ free -m
          total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           2000         337         961          47         700        1444
Swap:          1021           0        1021
```

In the nginx config file there is a bunch of stuff but here is the relevant code:

```
upstream php {
            server unix:/tmp/php-cgi.socket;
            server  127.0.0.1:9000;
    }

location ~ \.php$ {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
            fastcgi_read_timeout 150;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }
```

In the file /etc/php/7.0/fpm/pool.d/www.conf  The listen directive is

```
listen = /run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock
```

In the directory run/php there is a file php7.0-fpm.sock

```
server:/run/php$ ls
php7.0-fpm.pid  php7.0-fpm.sock  php7.1-fpm.pid  php7.1-fpm.sock
```

The only way I can get the 502 bad gateway error to be removed from the browser is to do the following:

```
sudo systemclt stop php7.0-fpm
sudo systemctl start php7.0-fpm
```

I need to do this many times a day....of course this is not a solution.  It is just restarting the service.

I noticed that in the nginx config file there are two function "upstream php" and "location  ~.php"    These two are pointing to different locations.   Could this be an configuration error?

Not really sure as one is pointing to a server and the other a file location.

Any help would be great.

Spineless

Comment: FIrst, it seems like the php-fpm process is crashing, you should check those logs. Second, the upstream it's defined, but it's never used, the call that runs is line 9, also the values after the first ";" are not being passed properly (";" ends the command )

Comment: It's very likely a configuration error, but `upstream php` would be referred to later on in the config by `@php`.  Without the full configuration you have, it'd be hard to say otherwise.  But since you don't *call* @php, i'm more inclined to think it's an error in your code somewhere (because one of those lines you stated isn't valid).  Also make sure your php7.0-fpm process isn't crashing, it looks like it may be.

Comment: Not sure if it's relevant but do you know what the purpose of `$document_root$fastcgi_script_name;` is in the fastcgi_pass line? I don't use that in my conf. In my nginx conf's I simply use `fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;` Also I'm not sure you even need the upstream block as my fpm set up works fine without it.

Comment: I checked the php7.0-fpm log and I am seeing this.         [08-Feb-2017 12:36:27] NOTICE: Terminating ...
[08-Feb-2017 12:36:27] NOTICE: exiting, bye-bye!
[08-Feb-2017 12:36:27] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 25967
[08-Feb-2017 12:36:27] NOTICE: ready to handle connections
[08-Feb-2017 12:36:27] NOTICE: systemd monitor interval set to 10000ms
[08-Feb-2017 12:36:31] WARNING: [pool www] server reached pm.max_children setting (5), consider raising it

Comment: the $document_root$fastcgi_script_name; is commented out in my code....sorry about that.

Comment: We had an issue with one of our nginx proxy set ups getting overloaded with connections and we had to add the following options to the nginx conf. 
    worker_processes  auto;
    worker_rlimit_nofile 30000;
    events {
        worker_connections  10000;
    }

We did some tuning based on our system resources to get those numbers, you should do some more research on those options and see if they help.

Comment: Since I saw an error in the php7.0-fpm.log  I increased the pm.max_children to 35,  pm.start.server=30, pm.max.server=31. in the file /etc/php/7.0/pool.d/www.conf....this action stopped the errors in the php7.0-fpm.log....hope this solves the issues.